# How do i resign the keyboard from a text field in my app settings

Tags: ios, keyboard, resignfirstresponder, root.plist

IOS xcode, in my root.plist i have 3 text fields. The user is able to change the strings for these fields which then saves in the nsUserDefault.  While in the app settings page if the user click on the field to edit it the keyboard pops up.  when they hit return focus moves to the next text field. Moving the focus off the text fields does not resignFirstResponder.

Since this is the Apple Settings page I don't have a way to assign view controller to create my method to resign the keyboard.

How do I resignFirstResponder from the app setting page.

Answer (score 1):

you won't be able to do that...**settings** is a **native** **iOS** app..apple does not provide return in the text fields there..user has to navigate back...to hide the keyboard

Comment: Thank you, My research lead me to believe this was the case but wanted a second opinion from experts since I have only started with ios development 6 weeks ago.  Still learning.